# Facebook public objects not retrievable through Graph API or FQL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am searching the public feed and once I get the objects I want to get more information on them.  I login with an auth token and when I try to get more information through both the graph API and FQL I get the following results.

Graph API - I run the following request "https://graph.facebook.com/{pid or object_id}" 
Results - I get the error "Unsupported get request."

FQL query - I run something like "Select {fields} from photo where pid = '{pid}'" 
Document - "To read the photo table you need any valid access_token if it is public and owned by the Page."
Results - I get an empty data array.

This used to work and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or this functionality has changed?

Thank you for any insight you might have,
Stefanie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook says this is "By Design" via developers.facebook.com/bugs/285682524881107